# Bitcoin Source Code genesisOutputScript

Tags: open-source, source-code

I am checking bitcoin source code to learn forking a coin better,

in this link

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp

Line 52 has scratched my mind, what is that for? Should that be changed while forking a coin?

I know lines 124 and 125 are set after the first genesis block is mined, can someone explain me what line 52 does, and how it affects the blockchain?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code for genesis block:
https://github.com/nasa8x/genesis-block

Comment: Hello nasa8x and welcome to the forum. We appreciate your contribution. There is a slight issue with your post though. OP is asking for the idea behind line 52 of a specific file. Your answer just shows a generic link to another github. It does not provide any help, and also avoids for other readers to be able to understand the discussion. Can you rework your answer, to provide a more specific reply?